# How do I create a list of matrices based on lists I have?

Tags: list-manipulation

Okay, so let's say I have these lists and a number

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {4, 5, 6};
```

And now I want to create 3 matrices that each look like this

```
M = {{n^2 - b^2, a*b}, {b*a, n^2 - a^2}}
```

My desired output is that `M` is a list of 3 matrices, where

```
M = {M[[1]], M[[2]], M[[3]]}
```

and

```
M[[i]] = {{n^2 - b[[i]]^2, a[[i]]*b[[i]]}, {b[[i]]*a[[i]], n^2 - a[[i]]^2}}
```

I know I could use `Table` to do this, but I guess there is a more elegant method. Thanks!

Comment: You have `n[[i]]` in your code.  Is `n` also a list of numbers?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. `n` should be a single number and `n[[i]]` makes no sense, it should be just `n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can do one of the three following, among others:

```
{{n^2 - #2^2, #1 #2}, {#2 #1, n^2 - #1^2}} & @@@ Transpose[{a, b}]

Table[{{n^2 - b[[i]]^2, a[[i]] b[[i]]}, {a[[i]] b[[i]], n^2 - a[[i]]^2}}, {i, 1, Length@a}]

MapThread[{{n^2 - #2^2, #1 #2}, {#2 #1, n^2 - #1^2}} &, {a, b}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {4, 5, 6};
Transpose@MapThread[List, {{n^2 - b^2, a*b}, {b*a, n^2 - a^2}}, 2]
```